# I am trying to make android activity with 3 spinners, and third spinner will display options on based of selection of first and second

Tags: java, android

I am making an activity with 3 spinners, First spinner only have one value for now but second spinner have total of six values. I want populate 3rd spinner on base of items selected on second spinner (because first spinner only have 1 item). Can any one explain how can I do it?

I thought about doing it with switch case but I don't know how I can store spinner values in variable. I also searched for it on google and found onItemSeleted() method but I cant understand how to use it.

XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ENOTES">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Department_text"
    android:layout_width="144dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
    android:text="Department"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/department_text2"
    android:layout_width="144dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:text="Subject"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sem_spinner" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Sem_text"
    android:layout_width="144dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:text="Semester"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dept_spinner" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/dept_spinner"
    android:layout_width="144dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Department_text" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sem_spinner"
    android:layout_width="144dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Sem_text" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/subject_spinner"
    android:layout_width="144dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/department_text2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/get_notes_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.888"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.959" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

java :

```
package com.example.project;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Adapter;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Spinner;

    import java.util.List;

    public class ENOTES extends AppCompatActivity
    {

    Spinner dept_spinner, sem_spinner, subject_spinner;
    Button get_notes_button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enotes);

    //Variable Initializations
    dept_spinner = findViewById(R.id.dept_spinner);
    sem_spinner = findViewById(R.id.sem_spinner);
    subject_spinner = findViewById(R.id.subject_spinner);
    get_notes_button = findViewById(R.id.get_notes_button);

    //Setting dept_spinner adapter
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ad_dept = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
    R.array.department_names, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    ad_dept.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    dept_spinner.setAdapter(ad_dept);

    //setting sem_spinner adapter
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ad_sem = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
    R.array.sem_names, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    ad_sem.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sem_spinner.setAdapter(ad_sem);


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User selected item listener to get selected option for first two spinner and then show data in third spinner according to that

```
String a;
String b;

spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            // assign data to 'a'
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }
});

spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            // assign data to 'b'
setDatatoSpinner3(a,b)
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }
});

function setDatatoSpinner3(String a, String b){
// your data logic here
}
```

Updated code according to your code

```
package com.example.project;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Adapter;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Spinner;

    import java.util.List;

    public class ENOTES extends AppCompatActivity
    {

        Spinner dept_spinner, sem_spinner, subject_spinner;
        Button get_notes_button;

        String dept_selection = "", sem_selection = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enotes);

        //Variable Initializations
        dept_spinner = findViewById(R.id.dept_spinner);
        sem_spinner = findViewById(R.id.sem_spinner);
        subject_spinner = findViewById(R.id.subject_spinner);
        get_notes_button = findViewById(R.id.get_notes_button);

        //Setting dept_spinner adapter
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ad_dept = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
        R.array.department_names, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ad_dept.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dept_spinner.setAdapter(ad_dept);

        //setting sem_spinner adapter
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ad_sem = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
        R.array.sem_names, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ad_sem.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sem_spinner.setAdapter(ad_sem);

        dept_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                dept_selection = ad_dept.get(position);
            }
        
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }
        });

        sem_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                sem_selection = ad_sem.get(position);
            }
        
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }
        });


        }


        function updateSubjects(String dept, String sem){

        //setting sem_spinner adapter
        
        if(dept.equals('CIVIL') && sem.equals('1st') ){
        
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ad_subj = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
            R.array.civil_1st_sem, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        } else if(dept.equals('CIVIL') && sem.equals('2nd') ){
        
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ad_subj = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
            R.array.civil_2nd_sem, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        }


        ad_subj.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        subject_spinner.setAdapter(ad_subj);


        }
    }
```

Comment: check updated code, it should be like this, you can change data logic in function according to yours